# Sub-views in Angular UI router and Controller inheritance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have a view state like this, with 3 views:

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.tracker').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tracker', {
        url: '/tracker',
        controller: 'TrackerController as tracker',
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Parcel Tracker',
          access: 'public',
          bodyClass: 'tracker'
        },
        resolve: {
          HistoryResolve: function($log, MockDataFactory) {
            return MockDataFactory.query({
              filename: 'trackingdata'
            });
          }
        },
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker.html'
          },
          'controls@tracker': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-controls.html'
          },
          'content@tracker': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-details.html'
          }
        }
      });

  });

})();
```

I want to use the controller `TrackerController` for all the views in the state.  I thought they would simple inherit the parent one.

But so far, even a simple log does not show in the console.  The controller is

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.tracker').controller('TrackerController', function($log, HistoryResolve) {

    var _this = this;

    // _this.packageHistory = HistoryResolve;

    $log.debug('foo');


  });

})();
```

So, my console should read "foo" regardless, yes?  Nothing in the console. No errors.  The works fine, the views load the templates.  I am only stuck on the controller.  I've never run into this.

**UPDATE**
OK, I am trying to define a parent state, and assign the controller to that.  However, what I have below is no yielding nothing at all in the browser...

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.tracker').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tracker', {
        url: '/tracker',
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'TrackerController as tracker',
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Parcel Tracker',
          access: 'public',
          bodyClass: 'tracker'
        },
        resolve: {
          HistoryResolve: function($log, MockDataFactory) {
            return MockDataFactory.query({
              filename: 'trackingdata'
            });
          }
        }
      })
    .state('tracker.details', {
        url: '/tracker/details',
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker.html'
          },
          'controls@tracker': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-controls.html'
          },
          'content@tracker': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-details.html'
          }
        }
      });

  });

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define named views (using the `views` property, aka "named views"), the template properties of the state are overriden by each named view. From the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#views-override-states-template-properties):

> If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and templateProvider will be ignored. So in the case that you need a parent layout of these views, you can define an abstract state that contains a template, and a child state under the layout state that contains the 'views' object.

Note that a template is always paired with a controller. So since it doesn't use the template properties, there's no need for it to instantiate the controller. You have two choices:

- Use specify the controller for each view. This will instantiate a controller for each named view, probably not what you want.
- Create a parent state to this state, which is abstract and uses the controller. Note that your state above doesn't have a child/parent relationship, it's just one state w/some named views.

Comment: I have tried doing that (see amended question), but I must've missed something since now no views display at all.

Comment: Never mind, I see now I needed to define a templateUrl for the parent, and remove the '' view from the child.  Not sure if that's the only way, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Steve sometimes instead of creating a template file and using `templateUrl`, I use the `template` property and give it a simple string value:  `template: "<div ui-view></div>"` (when the parent doesn't need to have any HTML)